# Listing files in a dropdown menu linking to these

Tags: javascript, php, dropdown

I want a dropdown menu to appear which lists all PDF files i have in a directory and making each entry clickable, linking to the specific file.

I have already tried a lot and the Dropdown menu with the PDFs listed actually shows up, but when i tried adding a Button next to it to open a new page with the PDF file, but when clicking it, nothing would happen at all

```
<select name="PdfFile" id="target" class="pdfliste">
<option value="">- Wähle Datei -
<?php 
$dirPath = dir('beispiel');
$imgArray = array();
    while (($file = $dirPath->read()) !== false)
{
   $imgArray[ ] = trim($file);
}
$dirPath->close();
sort($imgArray);
$c = count($imgArray);
for($i=0; $i<$c; $i++)
{
    echo "<option value=\"" . $imgArray[$i] . "\">" . $imgArray[$i] . "\n";
}

?>
</select>
    <input type="button" class="button-spec" value="Visit Link!"
         onclick="goToNewPage(document.dropdown.PdfFile)">';
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function goToNewPage() {
  if(document.getElementById('target').value) {
    window.location.href = document.getElementById('target').value;
  }
}
```

Comment: "wouldn't work" how, exactly? What goes wrong? A JS error? Links to the wrong file? Some other issue? Please be specific, and also indicate what debugging you've done so far (hint, if you haven't done any yet, like stepping through your JS code in the debugger to check variable values, then please do some before replying). Bear in mind we can't see any of your actual data, or how you store your files etc etc. Nor can we read your browser console, or your disk...or your mind. Thanks.

Comment: P.S. a small observation: `goToNewPage(document.dropdown.PdfFile)` ...putting `document.dropdown.PdfFile` here doesn't make any sense, because the `function goToNewPage()` doesn't define any input parameters, as you can see. What was this value supposed to be, and what was its purpose supposed to be? Your function doesn't define it, and makes no attempt to make use of it.

Comment: Have you tried debugging to see the error the browser is throwing? If using Chrome,  launch Developers Tools (Ctrl+Shift+J in Windows, Ctrl+Option+J on Mac). You need to be a bit more specific on what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks for the tipp.
This is the error its throwing when clicking the button
------

    dokumente.php:85 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'PdfFile' of 
    undefined
        at HTMLInputElement.onclick (dokumente.php:85)

Comment: So clearly that's related to the `document.dropdown.PdfFile` bit. The error is telling you that `document.dropdown` is undefined, and therefore it cannot read any property called `PdfFile`, because it's trying to read it from something which itself does not exist. But anyway, this is the piece of code which I've already mentioned does not appear to have any purpose. Just remove that, change the code to `onclick="goToNewPage()"` and try again.

Comment: @ADyson thanks man, now its redirecting me. However, its redirecting me to basepath/PDFNAME . Im working in basepath/content/documents/  and have my files in this folder. How would i add that?

I though "window.location.href" would take the current URL path of the PHP page the script is executed in

Comment: Is t because i have this in my header?

Could it be because i have this in my header?

    <base href="https://MYWEBSITE/basepath/" />

Comment: could be, yes. I'm not actually familiar with that tag. I don't know what you're currently outputting in your option values, but maybe you could simply do `echo "<option value=\"/content/documents" . $imgArray[$i] . "\">"` etc to pre-pend the subfolder to the path which gets passed to window.location.href

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two things now:

1. Your HTML Option tag weren't closed

`echo "<option value=\"" . $imgArray[$i] . "\">" . $imgArray[$i] . "</option>\n";`

2. Javascript at the button onClick was wrong

`<input type="button" class="button-spec" value="Visit Link!"
         onclick="goToNewPage()">`

Now you can choose one file, click on the button and get redirected.

For more information here now:
First the option tags weren't closed (maybe automatic by browser), but so you had file1, file2, etc. in one HTML tag. (makes no difference, as I tested it out without the closed option tags)

If you want to use the onclick with the files name you will need to correct your function so it gets the input, lemme give you the example for that:

`<input type="button" class="button-spec" value="Visit Link!" 
  onclick="goToNewPage(document.getElementById('target').value)">`

`function goToNewPage(newPageUrl){window.location.href = newPageUrl;}`

Hope this helps :)

Comment: thanks man, This is working like a charm aswell! However, its redirecting me to basepath/PDFNAME . Im working in basepath/content/documents/ and have my files in this folder. How would i add that? I though "window.location.href" would take the current URL path of the PHP page the script is executed in –

Could it be because i have this in my header?

    <base href="https://MYWEBSITE/basepath/" />

Comment: Yeah, either delete that base tag or direct to the right path in you href (kinda like window.location.href = "content/documents/"+newPageUrl)

Comment: Ah im having another question!
Currently, my dropdown menu shows all the files (which is great) but it also lists ".", ".." and "@eaDir"

I tried adding something like 
----------------     $ignoredFiles = array('.', '..', '_notes', '@eaDir', 'index.html');
but nothing happened, I cant figure out when to execlude this piece

Comment: ah, though that you will be comming up with this :P
based on your code i just added edited it like this and checked for the file inside the ignoredfiles, if the file isn't in the ignoredFiles array it gets added -> shows up inside the dropdown.
$ignoredFiles = array('.', '..', '_notes', '@eaDir', 'index.html');
$imgArray = array();
    while (($file = $dirPath->read()) !== false)
{
 if(!in_array($file, $ignoredFiles)){
     $imgArray[ ] = trim($file);
 }
}

Comment: Top. Thanks buddy haha!